# В CGI Python NoneType объект не имеет атрибута 'read'

Tags: python, cgi

Делаю CGI сайт на Python, столкнулся с ошибкой:

```
Error in sys.excepthook:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\cgitb.py", line 270, in __call__
        self.handle((etype, evalue, etb))
      File "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\cgitb.py", line 275, in handle
        self.file.write(reset())
    ValueError: underlying buffer has been detached

    Original exception was:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\\xd1\xe0\xe9\xf2\\cgi-bin\\wall.py", line 26, in <module>
        fout.write(fileitem.file.read())
    AttributeError: \'NoneType\' object has no attribute \'read\'
```

Предположение. По всей видимости в объекте MiniFieldStorage все поля None, а конструктор заполняет только два из них: `value` и `name`.

```
class MiniFieldStorage:

    """Like FieldStorage, for use when no file uploads are possible."""

    # Dummy attributes
    filename = None
    list = None
    type = None
    file = None
    type_options = {}
    disposition = None
    disposition_options = {}
    headers = {}

    def __init__(self, name, value):
        """Constructor from field name and value."""
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        # self.file = StringIO(value)

    def __repr__(self):
        """Return printable representation."""
        return "MiniFieldStorage(%r, %r)" % (self.name, self.value)
```

В гайдах и решениях других людей всё работает (поля возвращаются не `None`).

```
https://gist.github.com/ohtomi/74c49a4f6b460d9097f7
https://cgi.tutorial.codepoint.net/file-upload
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40280267/file-upload-using-python-with-cgi
```

Там, как вы можете заметить, люди без проблем возвращают и `fileitem.filename`, и `fileitem.file.read()`. У меня возникло предположение, что проблема в версии Python (у меня стоял 3.9.6), я переустановил до более старой, но безуспешно - ничего не заработало, затем переустановил до самой последней - тоже не работает.

Мой код:

**`cgi-bin/wall.py`**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import cgi
import html

import sys, os
import codecs

import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout.detach())
sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())

from _wall import Wall
wall = Wall()
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

fileitem_str = ""
if "in_question_f" in form:
    fileitem = form["in_question_f"]
    fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.value)

    with open('./files/' + fn, 'wb') as fout:
        # .write(fileitem.file.read())
        fout.write(fileitem.file.read())

    fileitem_str = str(fileitem.value)

question = html.escape(form.getfirst("in_question", "None"))
answer = html.escape(form.getfirst("in_answer", "None"))

if question != "None" and answer != "None":
    wall.publish(question, answer)

str_form = str(form)

pattern = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>AnswersBase</title>
</head>
<body>
    <font face="Arial">
    <form enctype = "multipart/form-data" action="/cgi-bin/wall.py">
        Введите ВОПРОС: <input type="text" name="in_question"><input type="file" name="in_question_f" accept=image/png,image/jpeg><br />
        Введите ОТВЕТ: <input type="text" name="in_answer"><input type="file" name="in_answer_f" accept=image/png,image/jpeg><br />
        <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>

    <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Вопрос</th>
        <th>Ответ</th>
    </tr>
    {posts}
    </table>
    </font>
    {form}
    {fileitem_str}
</body>
</html>
'''

print('Content-type: text/html\n')

print(pattern.format(posts=wall.html_list(), form = form, fileitem_str = fileitem_str))
```

**`cgi-bin/_wall.py`**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json

class Wall:
    WALL = 'cgi-bin/wall.json'

    def __init__(self):
        """Создаём начальные файлы, если они не созданы"""
        try:
            with open(self.WALL, 'r', encoding='utf-8'):
                pass
        except FileNotFoundError:
            with open(self.WALL, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                json.dump({"posts": []}, f)

    def publish(self, question, answer):
        with open(self.WALL, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            wall = json.load(f)
        for post in wall['posts']:
            if post['question'] == question:
                return 0
        wall['posts'].append({'question': question, 'answer': answer})
        with open(self.WALL, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(wall, f, indent=4)

    def html_list(self):
        with open(self.WALL, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            wall = json.load(f)
        content = ''
        for post in wall['posts']:
            content += f"<tr><td>{post['question']}</td> <td>{post['answer']}</td></tr>"
        return content
```

**`index.html`**

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL=cgi-bin/wall.py" />
</head>
```

**`start_server_windows.py`**

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("", 8080)
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Скорее всего, мне нужно откатиться до "правильной" версии cgi, но если так, то как? Какую бы версию Python я не устанавливал, везде в объекте `MiniFieldStorage` поля `None`, и пресловутый конструктор.
Также нашёл пост с ошибкой, примерно такой же, как и у меня, но её решение у меня уже реализовано - [https://coderoad.ru/20146517/cgi-python-скрипт-похоже-не-получает-загруженный-файл-из-формы-html](https://coderoad.ru/20146517/cgi-python-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-html)

Comment: `method="post"` пробовали? Как указано по вашей ссылке.

Comment: Да, действительно помогло добавление `method="post"`, благодарю!